# Jena Dataset Listener

Tags: jena, tdb

Thanks to ModelChangedListener, I can monitor changes in a `Model` as explained in Jena documentation ([Event handling in Jena](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/event-handler-howto.html)).

```
Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(); 
ModelChangedListener L = new MyListener();
m.register(L);
```

However, in my project, I want to monitor a `Dataset` for changes to run a code after something occurred in the default graph or one of the named graphes of the `Dataset`.

What I want to do is simply triggering events after executing such a query against a `Dataset`:

```
PREFIX d: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/data#>
PREFIX dm: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/demo#>
INSERT DATA
{
    d:x dm:tag "one" .
    d:x dm:tag "two" .
    GRAPH d:g1
    {
        d:x dm:tag "three" .
        d:x dm:tag "four" .
    }
}
```

to detect that "one" "two" were added to the default graph, and "three" "four" where added to g1.

With this code, I can't even detect changes happening in the default graph of the `Dataset`, let alone detecting changes in named graphs.

```
Dataset ds = RDFDataMgr.loadDataset(ONTOLOGY_PATH);
Model defaultModel = ds.getDefaultModel();
ModelChangedListener modelChangedListener = new MyListener();
defaultModel.register(modelChangedListener);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `DatasetGraphMonitor` which takes a `DatasetChanges` for processing changes.

Listening to models is unreliable if it works at all because the changes may be going straight to the dataset.   A `DatasetFactory.createGeneral` data should work for models added by the application but in your example `d:g1` may not. You would have to add a way to create the model. The engine for this is `DatasetGraphMapLink`.

But `DatasetGraphMonitor` / `DatasetChanges` is easier.

An alternative is [RDF Delta](https://afs.github.io/rdf-delta/), and `DatasetGraphChanges` where the changes are delivered with transaction boundaries.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Using DatasetChangesCapture solved the problem.